# Accessing values stored in bytes in a memory address

Tags: c, memory, int, byte

Lets say i allocated some memory and have a pointer to it.

```
 Int *k = malloc(100);
```

After storing data from a file in this memory address is it possible to retrieve the value at the nth byte? Say for example I wanna know the value of the int at the first byte.

Comment: Use array indexing and casting the array, e.g. `char c=((char *)k)[n];`

Comment: You are confusing me: do you want to retrieve a _byte_ or an _int_? Do you want to get a _byte_ from an array of ints, or an _int_ from an array of bytes?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to retrieve the ninth index of the int array, not the ninth byte. In that case, just do `int someval = k[9];` The other thing to note is malloc will allocate in bytes, if you want enough memory for 100 integers then you need `malloc(100*sizeof(int));`

Comment: Doesnt the address returned by malloc point to the 100 bytes as a whole? In that case isn't using k[9]  supposed to move 9 units from that address?

Comment: I wanna check to see if the 1st byte is 0xff

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pointer like an array, an indexed access is "just" syntactic sugar for a de-reference of an address with an offset. `k[n]` is the same as `*(k + n)`.

To check the first byte of any memory pointed to by `k` for `0xFF` write this:

```
if (*((char *)k + 0) == 0xFF) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Or write this:

```
if (((char *)k)[0] == 0xFF) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Or write this:

```
char* p = (char*)k;
if (p[0] == 0xFF) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Please be aware that the type of elements the pointer points to is important. Try this example, and learn from its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int* pi = malloc(100 * sizeof *pi);
    if (!pi) {
        puts("Memory allocation error!");
        return 1;
    }

    pi[3] = 23;

    char* pc = (char*)pi;
    printf("%d\n", pc[3 * sizeof (int)]);

    printf("pi: %p %p\n", pi, pi + 3);
    printf("pc: %p %p\n", pi, pc + 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried but it says comparing a char with 255 is always false. :/

Comment: Oh yes, that's correct because of integer promotion, my fault. `char` has a range from -128 to 127, and `0xFF` equals 255 so the comparision will never be true. Now you have some alternatives: 1. Cast `0xFF` with `(char)`. 2. Change `char` into `unsigned char` which has a range from 0 to 255. 3. Compare against -1. *But this is another issue, your question how to access an arbitrary byte is answered.*